# JSON response being sent character by character?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, datatable

In a MVC structure using Razor and C#, I am attempting to display data from my database into a jquery DataTable. However, I'm having an issue with the way the JSON data is being serialized and interpreted by the datatable.

**Javascript (on a CSHTML page):**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        var validBarcode = @Model.ActiveBarcode.ToString();
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("ParseLogChangesData", "Article")',
                "dataSrc": '',
                "data": {barcode: barcode},
                "type":"POST"
            },
            "columns":  [
                {data: 'Header1'},
                {data: 'Header2'},
                {data: 'Header3'},
                {data: 'Header4'},
                {data: 'Header5'},
                {data: 'Header6'},
                {data: 'Header7'}
            ]
        });
});
</script>
```

**ParseLogChangesData (in the controller)**:

```
public ActionResult ParseLogChangesData(string barcode)
{
    if (barcode!= null && barcode!= "0")
    {
        Changelog log = new Changelog(barcode);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);
        return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

The log object is constructed from a LINQ Query to my database.

The "json" string being returned by ParseLogChangesData contains a list of objects formatted thusly:

> "[{\"Header1\":\"Value1\",\"Header2\":\"Value2\",\"Header3\":\"Value3\",\"Header4\":\"Value4\",\"Header5\":\"Value5\",\"Header6\":\"Value6\",\"Header7\":\"Header7\"},{\"Header1\":\"Value1\",[...]}

From that data I should be able to construct a jquery DataTable, as it appears to be formatted properly according to the examples on datatables.net.

However, if I look at the response being sent in the browser (here shown in Firefox, but I have the same problem with IE11 which is what needs to work):
[image: error in json]

And so on for each object.

Thus obtaining an error like so:

[image: error ie10]

Because when jquery.DataTables tries to do its job:

```
// Got the data - add it to the table
                    for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ ) {
                        _fnAddData( settings, aData[i] );
                    }
```

aData.length is 4976...and it won't find "Header1" first, but "H"!

I may be missing something with the way the data is being serialized, but I just don't know what it could be. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you need to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);`? can't you just `return Json(log)`? It looks like it's getting stringified twice.

Comment: You're serializing the string into a char array.

Comment: Seems there are no `dataType: json` on client-side AJAX request above, try using it as complementary of `return Json(log);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ParseLogChangesData` function. Replace:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);
return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

With:

```
return Json(log);
```

Comment: I think there is no need for `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` because it is a `post` verb.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai: That makes it even more simple :-)

Comment: Ah, well, I do feel stupid now... It was getting stringified twice as you said above, so a string was turned into a char, if I understand what happened correctly?

Comment: In any case, thanks for your help, that fixed it so I'll approve this solution once I can.

Comment: A (json) string was turned into a char array, @FrédéricLiard :-)